# Combine Pandas dataframes with similar columns

Tags: python, pandas

If I have 2 Pandas DataFrames that look like this:

dframe1:

|  | col_a | col_b | col_x | col_y | col_z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| source_1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |

dframe2:

|  | col_a | col_b | col_c | col_d | col_x | col_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| source_2 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |

How do I combine these into a new DataFrame which looks like this?

|  | col_a | col_b | col_c | col_d | col_x | col_y | col_z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| source_1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| source_2 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 0 |

I don't really care about the value of "source_1", "col_c" (or the other missing values); I can tidy that later.  For now, trying `pandas.concat`, I get this error: `Number of manager items must equal union of block items`.

Ideally, I'd like to be merge and keep the order of the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not getting that error with `pd.concat`. This is working on my end:

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5]], index=['df1'], columns=list('abxyz'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[6,7,8,9,10,11]], index=['df2'], columns=list('abcdxy'))
pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

|  | a | b | x | y | z | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| df1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5.0 | NaN | NaN |
| df2 | 6 | 7 | 10 | 11 | NaN | 8.0 | 9.0 |

Comment: Yes, many thanks; this does work.  The `fillna(0)` from Ribesh K cleans it up as well.

Comment: Seeing that this example was true showed me that my problem was elsewhere.  I discovered that I had a duplicate column.

Answer (score 1):

Using `append`:

```
dframe2.append(dframe1).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
   col_a  col_b  col_c  col_d  col_x  col_y  col_z
0      6      7    8.0    9.0     10     11    0.0
0      1      2    0.0    0.0      3      4    5.0
```